# Lyapunov Function and Comparison Lemma

Tags: nonlinear-system, estimation, lyapunov-functions

I am studying the book *Nonlinear Systems* from H.K. Khalil and I am stuck with a proof.

I have a Lyapunov function V that satisfies the condition
$$c_1\|y\|^2\leq V(t,x,y)\leq c_2\|y\|^2,$$
for all $y\in\{\|y\|\leq\rho_0\}$. Moreover, I have the following estimate on $\dot{V}$:
$$\dot{V}\leq\frac{-c_3}{2\epsilon}\|y\|^2+c_4L_3\|y\|,$$
for some $\epsilon$ sufficiently small.

From here, Khalil states that if at some time $t^*\geq t_0$, we have that
$$\|y(t^*,\epsilon)\|\leq\rho_0\sqrt{c_1/c_2}=:\mu,$$

then the solution $y(t,\epsilon)$ satisfies the exponentially decaying bound
$$\|y(t,\epsilon)\|\leq\mu\sqrt{c_2/c_1}e^{\frac{-\alpha(t-t^*)}{\epsilon}}+\epsilon\delta, \quad \forall \;\; t\geq t^*,$$

where $\alpha=c_3/4c_2$ and $\delta=2c_2c_4L_3/c_1c_3$.

I have the feeling that he is using the comparison lemma, however I am missing the details of how to get such a bound.

Any help is really appreciated.

**EDIT**

I figured out where the exponential bound is coming from.

Consider for a moment only
$$\dot{V}\leq\frac{-c_3}{2\epsilon}\|y\|^2,$$
then from the right-hand side on the top inequality, we get
$$\dot{V}\leq\frac{-c_3}{2\epsilon c_2}V.$$

Applying the comparison Lemma (Khalil, Lemma 3.4), we have
$$V(t,x(t),y(t))\leq V(t^*,x(t^*),y(t^*))e^{-A(t-t^*)},$$
where $A:=\frac{-c_3}{2\epsilon c_2}$. At this point, we use the left-hand side of the top inequality and get:
$$\|y(t)\|\leq \bigg[\frac{V(t,x(t),y(t))}{c_1}\bigg]^\frac{1}{2}\leq\bigg[\frac{V(t^*,x(t^*),y(t^*))e^{-A(t-t^*)}}{c_1}\bigg]^\frac{1}{2}$$
and now using the right-hand side of the top inequality it becomes
$$\bigg[\frac{V(t^*,x(t^*),y(t^*))e^{-A(t-t^*)}}{c_1}\bigg]^\frac{1}{2}\leq\bigg[\frac{c_2\|y(t^*)\|^2e^{-A(t-t^*)}}{c_1}\bigg]^\frac{1}{2}.$$
Finally, substituting $\mu$, $A$ and solving the square root, we get the exponential bound.

However, I am still struggling with the bound $\epsilon\delta$...